# Passing a variable to a function that is many calls deep

Tags: python

An abstract example:

```
def a():
  d_results = []
  for i in range(10):
    b(i, d_results)
  # do something that needs d_results

def b(i, d_results):
  # do clever b-stuff
  c(d_results)
  # more b-stuff

def c(d_results):
  # do clever c-stuff
  d(d_results)
  # more c-stuff

def d(d_results):
  result = ...
  d_results.append(result)
```

I have a function a() that performs an iteration that uses function b(). Function b() uses c() and c() uses d(). Now function d() also produces some results and in function a() I need to have a list of these results.

The above solution collects these results by passing a variable list `d_results` from one function to the other, to which d() is adding data and that is read by a(). This is very inconvenient, **because functions b() and c() don't even know what d_results is about! They're just blindly passing a variable.**

Can this be solved more elegantly? In a way that b() and c() don't have to care about `d_results`?

Global variables are not OK, because this is part of a http request handler and I need the data to be 'local' to a request.

I know that in XSLT (quite a different type of language, but hey...) there's a concept of 'tunneling' parameters through a chain of templates, but this is not known in Python, I suppose?

Or is this just a sign that my code isn't structured properly?

---

In case you're curious, the d() function stores some data on the GAE datastore and the d_results are Futures for these operations, for which I want to collect the results in function a(). It's not necessarily a()'s business, but for performance reasons the operations must be done async in d() and so I need *some* place to handle the Futures, which has to be a(), because that's where the iteration is taking place.

Comment: Look into making it an object and then you can have instance and class attributes, which can be used by any function in the object

Comment: While `global` variables are usually discouraged, you could declare `d_results` at the global level,  then functions `a()` and `d()` can use the `global d_results` to tell the interpreter you are accessing the global variable, and not a local variable of the same name.

Comment: Does `d()` actually depend on the results of any code executing in `b()` or `c()`? Is there a reason you can't directly invoke `d()` from `a()`? If there is a dependency on `b()` and `c()`, could you elaborate a little more in your example?

Comment: The design is iffy, but understandable if you need the efficiency of mutating `d_results` in place, rather than having functions return lists and making the caller responsible for combinging them into a final value for `a`. Global variables are an option, as well as making all four functions methods of a class dedicated to accumulating results in an instance attribute. (Both a global variable and the instance attribute basically act like an implicit argument to every function.)

Comment: Closures could be an option (assuming `b`, `c` and `d` can be defined *inside* `a`, rather than outside).

Comment: A language like Haskell would make use of a `State` monad to hide some of the boilerplate, but its mandate of pure functions and immutability means you use a style coding quite different from Python.

Comment: Some elaboration: a() is a class method: it's a webapp2.RequestHandler. b() and c() are methods in another class "Card", managing objects representing site content  (website shows a list of cards). d() is a function in a module. I can envision integrating d() in the class containing b() and c(), which operates on a single card object, but a() operates on the request object, iterating cards. Fitting this in a single class would make it monolithic, containing the whole app ;(

Answer (score 0):

You can make your entire application (or at least this portion of it) a class and have `d_results` as an attribute.

```py
class MyApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d_results = []
        
    def a(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.b(self,i)
        # do something that needs d_results by using self.d_results

    def b(self,i):
        # do clever b-stuff
        self.c(self)
        # more b-stuff

    def c(self):
        # do clever c-stuff
        self.d()
        # more c-stuff

    def d(self):
        result = ...
        self.d_results.append(result)
```